# Finding an .asmx on my own server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

I'm trying to install a vendor's software on my server that interfaces with the company's main server.  The problem comes in that I'm supposed to have a web service running on my server that should have been installed as part of the process, but I can't find it.  The vendor isn't being a help either.

My basic question is this:  is the location of an .asmx web service simply the IIS virtual directory + the name of the .asmx file, or are there more "hidden" routings I should look for buried in configurations?

I can rule out URL rewriting since my server doesn't have that module installed.  URL routing is still in play, however I'm not sure how I can browse the routing tables (since the code is pre-compiled).

In any case, since the manufacturer's URL is pointing to an .asmx file, there would need to be an .asmx file somewhere, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was led astray by thinking that a web service should be represented by a file in a web directory.  I thought there might be another species that existed independently of .asmx files, but I had it confirmed today when I finally found the web service after a reinstall, stopped IIS, and found I still was getting responses from the .asmx web service.  So it must operate with some sort of socket listener that pipes to a self-contained .asmx DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there should be no "hidden gems" so that you should expect a plain .asmx file in the application's folder. However, God only knows what happens if it's missing and the service still responds. You'd have to decompile the core application's module and see what happens in the possible custom routing routine. In ASP.NET with custom routing you could pretty much execute any url and redirect it anywhere.

Also, take a look at any rewrite rules that could also change a way requests are handled.